# Network Credentials defaults to old login name [Windows 10 -> Windows Server 2016]

Tags: windows, credentials

Recently one account on a Windows Server 2016 was renamed through the Computer Management option.

From another computer (Windows 10) I want to map a share on that server.

My issue is that the default login name comes up as it originally was.

Is there a way I can clear / reset this value to the adjusted login name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean the cached account for that user.

[image]

and clear the bad password inside that section; or edit it.

[image]

After that it should work as expected.